# How add a text over an arrow in a plot in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I plotted two points in a graph using R and connected the points with an arrow.
How can I add a text over the arrow.(Fixed Text) 
My codes are as following:

```
x<-y<-1
new.x<-2
new.y<-2  
Text<-"Direction"
plot(x, y, xaxt='n',yaxt='n',cex=10,pch=19,xlim=c(0,4), ylim=c(0,3))
points(new.x,new.y,cex=10,pch=19)
arrows(x, y, new.x, new.y, col = "orange",lwd=4,lty=4)
```

on the arrow I want to add a Text object ("Direction") on the arrow.

The image is as following:

[image: Arrow including a Text above it]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at using [text](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html)?

e.g,

```
x<-y<-1
new.x<-2
new.y<-2  
Text<-"Direction"
plot(x, y, xaxt='n',yaxt='n',cex=10,pch=19,xlim=c(0,4), ylim=c(0,3))
  points(new.x,new.y,cex=10,pch=19)
  arrows(x, y, new.x, new.y, col = "orange",lwd=4,lty=4)
  text(x=1.4, y=1.6, label=Text, srt=35)
```

[image: Picture output]

Depending on what you're doing, can probably programmatically sort out the coordinates for the text and the appropriate angle.